# I am trying a simple Compare 2 text files and print the diff between the 2

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;

public class CheckingTwoFilesAndComparing implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

static String FILE_ONE = "/Users/abextra/myText1.txt";
static String FILE_TWO = "/Users/abextra/myText2.txt";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        CompareFile(FILE_ONE, FILE_TWO);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private static void CompareFile(String fILE_ONE2, String fILE_TWO2)
        throws Exception {

    File f1 = new File("FILE_ONE");
    File f2 = new File("FILE_TWO");

    FileReader fR1 = new FileReader(f1);
    FileReader fR2 = new FileReader(f2);

    BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(fR1);
    BufferedReader reader2 = new BufferedReader(fR2);

    String line1 = null;
    String line2 = null;

    while (((line1 = reader1.readLine()) != null)
            &&((line2 = reader2.readLine()) != null)) {
        if (!line1.equalsIgnoreCase(line2)) {
            System.out.println("The files are DIFFERENT");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The files are identical");
        }

    }
    reader1.close();
    reader2.close();

   }
}
```

Here are contents of the 2 Text files that exist in the path mentioned in the code above

```
==myText1.txt===
1,This is first line, file
2,This is second line, file
3,This is third line , file
4,This is fourth line, file

==myText2.txt===
1,This is first line, file
2,This is second line, file
3,This is third  line, file
4,This is fourth line, file
5,This is fifth line, file
```

I am a newbie to java . I used eclipse debugger and I see that I keep getting "FileNot found"exception - can someone please help?
Thanks much!

Comment: what do you mean "print the diff between the 2"? Just test 2 file are same, or need to "Point out" the different lines?

Answer (score 4):

```
File f1 = new File("FILE_ONE");
File f2 = new File("FILE_TWO");
```

Try removing the quotes here. You declared FILE_ONE and FILE_TWO as variables earlier in your program, but you aren't calling them.  Instead, you've directly called a string "FILE_ONE," which will of course not be found.  So replace it with the parameters you passed to CompareFile...

```
File f1 = new File(fILE_ONE2);
File f2 = new File(fILE_TWO2);
```

And tell us if that takes care of it.

Comment: It actually looks like he would want to use the parameters String fILE_ONE2, String fILE_TWO2 passed into the method.

Comment: Couple other things, your compareFile method takes 2 parameters fILE_ONE2 and fILE_TWO2 and you never use them. You create a File object, then use that to create a FileReader object, check out the javadocs for io, you don't need all that.

Comment: @Joel Good catch.  I think he might still be okay the other way since they haven't changed at all from their static declaration in this implementation, but it should absolutely follow from the parameters since he went out of his way to make them.  I'll edit that.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the quotes from:

```
File f1 = new File("FILE_ONE");
```

and

```
File f2 = new File("FILE_TWO");
```

Also, make sure in the files' path `"/Users/abextra/myText1.txt"`, *"Users"* is really supposed to be uppercase.
On many systems, `/users/` is lowercase.

Comment: @Roflo Just a note, but I don't think the lowercase users bit is necessarily true for Windows 7.  Absolutely good practice in general to check your directories, though.

Comment: True, but it doesn't harm to _make sure_. :) Didn't know about the Macs and Windows..

Comment: I didn't know about the Mac bit either -- I had double-checked Windows 7 because that sounded off.  Good to know, guess we're all learning something here. :)

Answer (score 1):

Also The `FileNotFoundException` can be thrown when the file is open.
(this happens only when you try to write to an already opened file)

Try closing the file and then running the program.

Comment: Thanks for all the help - I did have the files open and removed the quotes File f1 = new File("FILE_ONE"); 
and used the correct param to pass the value to the calling function.